# Can't see program's output in the terminal after using fork and pipe in c

Tags: c, process, pipe, signals, fork

I'm supposed to write a program which creates 2 processes, connects between them with a pipe, and after a given time will end both processes and terminate.
one of the programs will write to the pipe, and the other will read from it and print it to STDOUT.
the reading process will be called first, then the pid will be passed to the second process so it will give SIGUSR1 signals to the first process, to tell it to read.
for some reason i never see the output in the terminal of the first process,
further more, it doesn't even print the line:"trying to exec1\n" which is where i call "execlp" for the process that prints.
here is the code for the 3 programs:

the main program:

```
#define STDERR 2
#define STDOUT 1
#define STDIN 0
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void alarmHandler(int sig);
void systemError();

char * intToString(int num , char number[4]);

static pid_t processId1, processId2;

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    pid_t pid1, pid2;
    sigset_t block_mask1;
    struct sigaction exitSig;
    sigfillset(&block_mask1);
    exitSig.sa_handler = alarmHandler;
    exitSig.sa_mask = block_mask1;
    exitSig.sa_flags  = 0;
    sigaction(SIGALRM, &exitSig, NULL);
    if (argc < 2){
            systemError();
    } else {
        int x = atoi(argv[1]);
        alarm(x);
    }
    int fields[2];
    if (pipe(fields)){
        systemError();
    }

    if ((pid1 = fork()) == 0){
        printf("trying to exec1\n");
        close(STDIN);
        dup(fields[0]);
        close(fields[0]);
        close(fields[1]);
        if(execlp("./ex2_inp", "./ex2_inp", NULL)){
            systemError();
        }
    } else {
        processId1 = pid1;
        if ((pid2 = fork()) == 0){
            char number[350];
            printf("trying to exec2\n");
            close(STDOUT);
            dup(fields[1]);
            close(fields[0]);
            close(fields[1]);
            char * pidString = intToString(processId1, number);
            if(execlp("./ex2_upd","./ex2_upd",pidString, NULL)){
                systemError();
            }
        } else{
            processId2 = pid2;
        }
    }

    close(fields[0]);
    close(fields[1]);
    pause();
    return 1;
}

/***********************
 * handler for alarm signal
 *************************/
void alarmHandler(int sig){
    kill(processId2, SIGINT);
    kill(processId1, SIGINT);
    exit(1);
}

/***********************
 * turn pid to string
 *************************/
char * intToString(int num , char number[350]){
    sprintf(number, "%d", num);
    return number;
}
```

ex2_inp:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void exitHandler(int sig);
void printHandler(int sig);
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

    sigset_t block_mask1, block_mask2;
    struct sigaction exitSig, print;
    sigfillset(&block_mask1);
    sigfillset(&block_mask2);
    exitSig.sa_handler = exitHandler;
    print.sa_handler = printHandler;
    print.sa_mask = block_mask2;
    exitSig.sa_mask = block_mask1;
    exitSig.sa_flags  = 0;
    print.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &exitSig, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &print, NULL);
    pause();
    return 1;
}

void exitHandler(int sig){
    printf("exiting1!\n");
    close(1);
    exit(1);
}

void printHandler(int sig){
    char * buffer[80];
    read(1, buffer, 80);
    printf("%s", buffer);
}
```

ex2_upd:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void exitHandler(int sig);

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    sigset_t block_mask1;
    struct sigaction exitSig;
    sigfillset(&block_mask1);
    exitSig.sa_handler = exitHandler;
    exitSig.sa_mask = block_mask1;
    exitSig.sa_flags  = 0;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &exitSig, NULL);
    printf("2's message\n");
    kill(atoi(argv[1]), SIGUSR1);
    pause();
    return 1;
}

void exitHandler(int sig){
    printf("exiting2!\n");
    close(0);
    exit(1);
}
```

thanks

Comment: Try using `fflush(stdout);` after calling `printf` and before calling `close` to make sure what is passed to `printf` is printed.

Comment: it's not helping, and i'm still not seeing the "2's message\n" that i'm supposed to get, printed by the first process

Comment: `printf()` is not async-safe. Also, the way you intend to send the signal is a race-condition. The signal may be sent *before* the receiver has called `sigaction()`.

Comment: what's the way to make sure it wasn't sent before that then? thanks

Comment: I'd start with learning the basics of C separately from multi-progamming.

Answer (score 0):

ex2_upd.c:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void exitHandler(int sig);

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    sigset_t block_mask1;
    struct sigaction exitSig;
    sigfillset(&block_mask1);
    exitSig.sa_handler = exitHandler;
    exitSig.sa_mask = block_mask1;
    exitSig.sa_flags  = 0;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &exitSig, NULL);
    printf("2's message\n");
    kill(atoi(argv[1]), SIGUSR1);
    sleep(1); /* This was pause - causing ex2_inp read() to wait forever, since read() on pipe needs to either fill buffer or END_OF_FILE, unless we make the filedescriptor in the read-end non-blocking via fcntl()  */
    return 1;
}

void exitHandler(int sig){
    printf("exiting2!\n");
    close(0);
    exit(1);
}
```

ex2_inp.c:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void exitHandler(int sig);
void printHandler(int sig);
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

    sigset_t block_mask1, block_mask2;
    struct sigaction exitSig, print;
    sigfillset(&block_mask1);
    sigfillset(&block_mask2);
    exitSig.sa_handler = exitHandler;
    print.sa_handler = printHandler;
    print.sa_mask = block_mask2;
    exitSig.sa_mask = block_mask1;
    exitSig.sa_flags  = 0;
    print.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &exitSig, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &print, NULL);
    pause();
    return 1;
}

void exitHandler(int sig){
    printf("exiting1!\n");
    close(1);
    exit(1);
}

void printHandler(int sig){
    char buffer[80]; /* removed * */
    read(0, buffer, 80);   /* stdin is fd=0, not 1 */
    printf("-> %s <-\n", buffer); /* added \n, forces new-line */
}
```